# How to delete queue in RabbitMQ with non-printable symbols

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

Somehow there are a few queues on my RabbitMQ server, which I can't delete.
There are a strange non-printable symbols in queue names.
When I click on such queue in RabbitMQ Managment page I see:

```
http://127.0.0.1:15672/#/queues/%2F/production.packet.create.0%2C%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00
```

And the content page of this queue is not loaded.
There are `\x00` characters in the queue name.

When displaying queues via

```
rabbitmqadmin list queues name
```

I see this queue as

```
| production.packet.create.0,                      |
```

I've tried to delete it with rabbitmqadmin via

```
rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=production.packet.create.0,
rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=production.packet.create.0,%00%00%00....
```

but it says that queue is not found!

So I have two questions:

1. How it could happen?
2. Is there any way to delete such queue?